# Buttons Flickering while using tkinter Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am trying to make a basic GUI using tkinter on Mac

The script runs fine but the button flicker. I have noticed that this flickering seems to be linked with cursor movement. How can I fix this?

I am using Pycharm, Python 3.8

Video of flickering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k8nM.jpg

Source code:

```
from tkinter import *


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        exitButton = Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.clickExitButton)
        exitButton.place(x=0, y=0)

        loggerButton = Button(self, text='Run Logger', command=self.clickLoggerButton)
        loggerButton.place(x=100, y=100)

    def clickExitButton(self):
        exit()

    def clickLoggerButton(self):
        print('seen')


root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.wm_title("Fard")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(background='red')
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: I have tested the same code on Repl.it and it worked fine, This makes me think this bug has something to do with rendering the window

Answer (score 0):

can I ask you what version of Mac you are using? I had same problem with python 3.8 that was preinstalled on Mac and then found [this](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#built-in-8-6-11).
So now I'm using python version 3.9 on Mac Monterey 12.4 and everything seems working correctly.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32119470)